# Is there a way to query a metric and do artimethic operations with its label?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am increasing a counter-metric which looks something like this:

```
COUTER_XY_TOTAL{processingStarted="2020-04-17T13:44:15.583",processingFinished="2020-04-17T13:44:18.082"}
```

I wonder if it's possible to query labels and do arithmetic operations with them.

Here a symbolic query:

```
avg(COUNTER_XY_TOTAL{processingFinished} - COUNTER_XY_TOTAL{processingStarted})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, label values are opaque strings. These two labels should be moved to two separate gauges in the application exposing them.